# React Matrial Multiselect defaultValue are not selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'k working on the React Material autocomplete component with [multiple-values checkbox](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values) and seems like there is a issue with defaultValue prop and the checkboxes example.

If I set defaultValue a item from the list, it will appear in the text input label, but it won't appear as checked in the autocomplete dropdown.
I tried to set the items as checked if exist in defaultValue, but that didn't solve the issue.

How can I set the defaultValue items to be set as checked in the autocomplete dropdown?

[Condsandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-c7rp7?file=/demo.js:0-2985)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      defaultValue={[{ title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 }]}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Checkboxes"
          placeholder="Favorites"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 }
];
```

[image]

Comment: Sandbox not working. I'm seeing this error `(0 , _utils.unstable_useId) is not a function`

Comment: @rzwnahmd try to do "enter" in the preview link field in top of the view output screen part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a value from a list to be set as the `defaultValue` for the `Autocomplete` component - you should use the exact value (which in your case - is the exact object that is part of the `options` that you have.

You can do this (for example) using the following:

```
<Autocomplete
    options={ top100Films }
    defaultValue={ [ top100Films[0] ] }
    ...
/>
```

Comment: This worked in the demo, Toda. Didn't solve issue because I'm fetching  values from api and the default value seem to be set only once and do react when the dropdownOptions are updated

Comment: You can do the same after the data is fetched - just make sure to put this in another variable and use that variable inside the `defaultValue`. The thing that you need to remember is that `([1] == [1]) == false`, because it's not the same object. The `Autocomlete` component checks if the values that you have inside the `defaultValue` (and also in the `value`, in case of controlled component) are the exact same objects - so you need to pass a reference.

Comment: it's not working if i use same option in one variable see for more. https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxestags-material-demo-forked-5xjtg?file=/demo.js

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh As mentioned in my answer - you need to use the exact object (and not a different object). the `<Autocomplete>` component expects a reference to the object, and if it's not the exact same object - if will not be the one that you marked as "selected". In javascript `{a: 1} !== {a:1}`, because they reference different objects.